# android adapter notifydatasetchanged not working properly

Tags: android, adapter

I have issue when image is not loaded after `notifyDataSetChanged` In overall i have startup class where i begin loading images from web and save them on device. And adapter uses images saved on device. So if i open my listview before i save images i see only my placeholder. And then if i return yo app then of course imageas ar loaded because theyre saved already.

creating adapter

```
adapter = new GridAdapter(getActivity(), grid, 6);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here i save image and notifying adapter.

```
try {
                FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(String.valueOf(id)+".jpg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(imageBytes);
                fos.close();
                try {
                    GridFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
```

.
And in adapter i use imageloading library but simply it just sets image from device(not async etc.)

```
        iLoader.displayImage("file:///"+mContext.getFileStreamPath
                (String.valueOf(position)).toString()+".jpg", holder.imageView, DataHolder.options, this);
```

Comment: what is GridAdapter ?

Comment: did you check my answer ? it applies to base adapter also. does it help?

Answer (score 0):

generally for an `Adapter`, `notifyDataSetChanged` only works if you use the add, insert, remove, and clear functions on the Adapter.

for e.g , if you have already added references to your images in the `adapter` (which seems probable , because the file already exists and you are writing new data to it), then if any property of your image changes (in your case, size) , `notifyDataSetChanged` would not do anything. it can only detect addition, removal.

(you haven't added your `GridAdapter` implementation, so that is all i can think of yet)